# Why do programs never execute in exactly the same time?

Tags: performance, runtime

This is more of a generic, technical question. I'm just curious about what the main factors in determining how fast or slow a computer program runs are?

For example, when I time Python code, the runtime always varies by at least +/- 0.02 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons of execution time variance. Variation of ~200ms looks plausible for a python script that runs for seconds. Main contributors here would be OS/scheduler and memory/cache. OS will serve interrupts on a core your script is running, and on blocking system calls it will run the scheduler, which will run background tasks on that core. While these tasks are running, they will pollute L1,L2 and L3 caches so that some part of data and code of that python script will be evicted to RAM. So memory references will always take different time each run, because you can never reproduce memory footprint of background tasks that interrupted your script.

If you are running on Linux, you may try scheduling your script to a CPU that was offlined from scheduler using isolcpu= kernel boot option, so you have less noise from other processes. You'll have orders of magnitude less variation then, but there will be still some coming from using shared resources - memory controllers, IO buses, shared last level cache.